# Как сборку прокинуть в nginx контейнер

Tags: reactjs, nginx, docker, docker-compose, devops

Подскажите, как после сборки в контейнере фронта добавить файлы в Nginx контейнер , если они изолированы. И как в таком случае лучше настроить ssl

```
    services:
      client:
        build:
          context: ./react-app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"

      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "433:433"
```

Comment: а что у вас в Dockerfile, можете показать? и у вас react app это только UI, без сервера на express например?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да просто ui. пока хочу ,просто запуститься для теста, понять как это работает

`
FROM node:12.15.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "build"]
`

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы UI приложение работало в Docker вам можно создать более простую конфигурацию, состоящую только из `nginx`, но будет использоваться [Multi Stage Build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx:alpine as base
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

На первом этапе (stage) мы собирает наше `ReactJS` приложение, после чего оно находится в папке `/usr/src/app/build`. А потом просто копируем его в `nginx`. Для этого подойдет и конфигурация по-умолчанию. Также если это просто для теста, то не думаю, что вам стоит заморачиваться с SSL, т.к. это потребует создания self-signed сертификатов, которым браузеры по-умолчанию не доверяют и сайт не откроется (нужно будет менять настройки браузера или ОС). Но, если интересно, про то как можно это сделать написано [тут](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  app:
    build: ./react-app
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: спасибо, это отличная альтернатива, но я ищу более изолированный от друг друга вариант.

Comment: @Mltd а чем этот вариант не изолированный (нет зависимостей от лишних вещей, приложение полность пакуется в докер, контейнер самодостаточен, его можно деплоить куда угодно)? у вас собирается UI приложения, это набор статических файлов, а nginx прекрасно хостит статику